# The /home/vagrant directory is missing from Ubuntu 16.04 (but there is in the 14.04)

Tags: vagrant, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

Hi Stackoverflow users,

I have a Vagrant installations with Ubuntu 16.04 but these lines cannot be run correctly, because the `/home/vagrant` directory is missing.

```
info "Create bash-alias 'app' for vagrant user"
echo 'alias app="cd /app"' | tee /home/vagrant/.bash_aliases

info "Enabling colorized prompt for guest console"
sed -i "s/#force_color_prompt=yes/force_color_prompt=yes/" /home/vagrant/.bashrc
```

However I run with Ubuntu 14.04 this shell code, and there were not any errors. It could run the above code correclty.

Do you have any idea where or how can I install the "home/vagrant" directory?

Answer (score 0):

Your box ships a default Vagrantfile where you can see

```
config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
```

you can check default Vagrantfile under the `.vagrant.d/boxes///Vagrantfile``

You can force the creation of the default folder by (re)adding

```
config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant'
```

in your own Vagrantfile

Comment: Yes, yes: this is added: `config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant` so I can see the `/vagrant` folder in the root, but the error says it is missing from the `home` directory!

Comment: okay I misread .. `/home/vagrant` should be there if you have a vagrant user. what is the box ? did you create yourself, if so did you make sure to create teh vagrant home directory for the vagrant user

Comment: Well, i use the official ubuntu/xenial box, btw the offical ubuntu/trusty contains the home/vagrant folder, but it seems the ubuntu team removed this from the xenial box.